# Unable to plot tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Here's the code I've written in `python3.6`. When I try to plot using tensorboard I see two graphs namely main and auxilary but they do not seem to correspond to my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1.0)
b = tf.constant(2.0)
c=a*b
sess=tf.Session()

writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("E:/python_prog",sess.graph)
print(sess.run(c))
writer.close()
sess.close().
```

I run the code in anaconda(Windows) prompt:

```
(tfp3.6) E:\python_prog>tensorboard --logdir="E:\python_prog"
Starting TensorBoard b'54' at http://DESKTOP-31KSN08:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the graph looks like?

Comment: There is a link above of the screenshot "enter image description here"

Comment: There might be graphs saved in that directory before. Or you might have executed some TF operations unintentionally (e.g. importing some graph from file, instantiating some layer, etc). Basically, graphs don't appear in directories by themselves. Somehow something wrote them there.